# node webkit - add custom folder outside of app.nw

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

Is it possible to add a folder that does not reside inside the app.nw zip file?

And if so, how is this done on win/mac/linux? Any link with more info?

Comment: Define "add a folder": Are you asking to require a module from outside app.nw or simply work with the File System?

Comment: I have a folder in which will be a database and a java (not javascript) program that connects to this db but I do not want this to be in a zip file due to performance issues. So if I could get it out there that would be great.. I understand for mac that it doesn't have to be zipped, so that's good. But what about linux and windows?

Comment: How does your node-webkit app interact with said DB?